# My code with linecast is not working in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I wanted to see if there is a gameobject between player and the enemy but even if there is nothing between them canshoot is always false. pos is assigned correctly.

Here is a chunck of code:

```
                RaycastHit2D x = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, pos);
                if (x.collider != null && x.collider.tag == "player")
                {
                    canshoot = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    canshoot = false;
                }
```

Comment: `Linecast` looks for colliders between two points. Your Enemy/Player colliders probably count as well. I'm also pretty sure this code won't compile cause `Linecast` returns a bool and you're trying to put that into a RaycastHit2D. You've probably confused it with `Raycast`.

Answer (score 1):

linecast should be replaced with raycast. Try this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).